# Remove all tags except for img tag

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, html

I need an regular expression or something else to remove all tags in a `contentEditable` `div`, but to keep `img` tag with specific `class` or `id`, how I can do this?

Now I use:

```
.replace(/(<\/?.*?>)/gi, '');
```

but it removes all tags.

I made this :

```
var element = document.getElementById("myDiv").children;
   for(var i=0; i<element .length;i++)
   {
     if(element[i].tagName != "IMG" || element[i].className != "requiredClassName")
     {
       element[i].parentNode.removeChild(element[i]);
     }
   }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions for HTML. HTML is not a regular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var child=document.getElementById('editableDIV').firstChild;
while(child) {
  var removeNode=null;
  if(child.tagName&&(child.tagName.toUpperCase()!=='IMG'||
     child.id!=='myid'||
     child.className!=='myclass')) removeNode=child;
  child=child.nextSibling;
  if(removeNode)removeNode.parentNode.removeChild(removeNode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*( if you need plain JS )*: Maybe the better way is to collect all elements then after check their class/id and perform action. Good idea is to use DOM, not regexp. DOM is for HTML elements manipulation.

*( or use jQuery )*: Simple code can do that thing. Just collect all div's children and check their class in .each() loop;

For e.g.:

```
$('#contentEditable').each( function( index ) {
    if( !this.is( 'img' ) && ( this.is('.someclass') || this.is('#someid') ) ) {
        this.remove();
    }
});
```

Hope it helps you.

P.S.:
Be careful when you are using greedy quantification `.*`

It will get all text between any `< >`, so if you have code listed below regexp `(<\/?.*?>)` will collect whole code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="portalLink">
            <a class="genu" href="http://stackexchange.com">Stack Exchange</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, i'd like to use plain Js, it's much easier with jquery, but i need plain Js

Comment: You can use childNodes and loop into it:

`for ( element in document.getElementById("contentEditable").childNodes ) {
 // Check element type/class/id or something
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
var editableDiv = document.getElementById("MyEditableDiv")
var editableDivImgs = editableDiv.getElementsByTagName("img")
for (var i = 0; i < editableDivImgs.length; i++) {
    if(editableDivImgs[i].className != "safe")
    {
        editableDivImgs[i].parentNode.removeChild(editableDivImgs[i])
    }
}
```

have you tried something like that?

Comment: thanks, but it should remove all tags (ex <div><span>..) but keep img tags.( and if it is possible to keep text from inside tags )

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing all other elements extract all imgs and concatenate them into a new string:

```
var regex = /<img.*?>/gmi;
var imgsOnly = '';
var img;
while( ( img = regex.exec(str) ) !== null ) {
    imgsOnly += img;
}
alert( imgsOnly );
```

Comment: this is not an option, because i need also to keep existing text